# What is the difference and connection between Atman and Nirguna Brahman

Tags: atma, brahman, purusha

There is a question that asks for the difference between jiva atman, Atman and Paramatman and it does not answer my inquiry. I wish to know about the difference between Atmans Ananda essence  and Nirguna Brahman the void and their connection?

Comment: Spirit is used to refer to atma. So I'm tagging it appropriately.

Comment: Duplicate doesn't mean that the linked post answers your question. It means that the answer to your question should go in the linked post for better interlinking. Btw *Atma = [Nirguna] Brahman*.

Comment: I have put a flag on this question because Spirit and Nirguna Brahman are different and this difference needs to be highlighted, seen and experienced, it is an entirely different question.

Comment: Spirit, soul and Atman refers to the same reality. actually spirit and soul are rough translation of Atman into English. see the meta post on [Sanskrit non-translatables](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/240/277)

Comment: @Pandya Atman and Spirit are the same blissful but they are different to Nirguna Brahman. I wish to know about the difference. One is spiritual bliss and the other is unlimited consciousness of emtyness. How are they connected ?

Comment: @Pandya as you said spirit is a rough translation for Atman would it be better to identify spirit as the Ananda Swarupa of Atman?